# Where do I store plasmoid's custom data?

Tags: kde-plasma, kde4, plasmoid

I'm new to KDE development. I wrote a [plasmoid](http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/Google+Calendar+Agenda?content=134032) that needs to store its data somewhere, namely - ical feeds need to be stored for offline usage.

While I could just write it to ~/.ical/ or some other location I would make up, I'd like to know what is the proper way of doing it - is there an API i can query about the path to store my private data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have received an answer on [KDE forums](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=64&t=91408):

> I think you can use [KStandardDirs](http://api.kde.org/4.5-api/kdelibs-apidocs/kdecore/html/classKStandardDirs.html) to create a directory inside the user's KDEHOME, in a specific path for your application (I suggest using "data" for that).

So my code now looks like this:

```
    def getDataPath(self, *parts):
        main_dir = str(KStandardDirs.locateLocal("data", "gcal-agenda"))
        dirs = [main_dir] + list(parts)
        return os.path.join(*dirs)
```

where "gcal-agenda" is the name of my plasmoid.